# What should be returned in model?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I'm very confused in this problem. For example, I have a "user" database table. What I've been taught in my university about MVC is:

> I must have a User model object which contain properties, setters and getters only. And a UserMapper (an other class, not in User model class) object which gets content from database and create an instance of User object then return it.

But some tutorials on Internet, and some of my co-worker do like this:

> Return rows from database right in User model object.

So, what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Whichever you prefer, as long as it works.  Just try to remain consistent in your own code.

Comment: @leftclickben i follow the first one. It's more complicate but it's what i learned. I just wanna know other opinion.

Comment: Off topic, but geez, it's all that edit necessary?...

Comment: sorry about my English!

Comment: @HungNV, you might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/727208) somewhat useful.